# Submitting iOS app to app store with Cocoa Pods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have installed Swift modules with Cocoa Pods on my iOS app which creates a new workspace within the project folder. When I am going through the process of submitting the app to the app store is there anything special I need to do to keep the Cocoa Pods intact with the project? I am afraid it will be submitted without the cocoa pods and declined as there are two main files in the project folder (the Cocoa Pods file (.xcworkspace) and the original file without Cocoa Pods (.xcodeproject)). How do I assure the correct one is submitted?

Comment: You are asking two completely different questions and the 2nd one is off-topic here. Stick to the main question.

Answer (score 3):

Once you use CocoaPods you only ever use the workspace. You never open the project file. You do all builds with the workspace. You do all testing with the workspace. You do your Archive build with the workspace.

If what you build and test during development includes everything then the Archive build should have everything as well.